# AJAX not outputting correct thing

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

So I'm trying to call a php method from javascript so I can query a database and get the results into my js functionality. Currently, the `'console.log(output)`' that is in my ajax is just outputting:

```
"array (size=1)
'action' => string 'getResults' (length=10)'"
```

Not really sure why it's doing this, it should be returning the query result which is just one entry from the database. Anyone have any idea? Any help is welcome! Thanks.

**Part of my Javascript file**:

```
function callPHP() {
    $.ajax ({

        type: "GET",
        datatype: "application/json",
        url: "BaseClass.php",
        data: { action : 'getResults' },
        //error: function(err){console.log(err)},
        success: function(output) {

            console.log(output);
            //alert(output);
        }
        //error, function(err){console.log(err)}
    });


}

callPHP();
```

**BaseClass.php:**

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    require("Conn.php");
    require("MySQLDao.php");

    $param=$_REQUEST['action'];

    echo var_dump($_GET);
    /*
    $handle = fopen("php://input", "rb");
    $param = '';
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $param .= fread($handle, 8192);
    }
    fclose($handle);
    */

    if (empty($param))
    {
        $returnValue["status"] = false;
        $returnValue["title"] = "Error";
        $returnValue["message"] = "No Data Recieved paige" .$param ."...";
        echo json_encode($returnValue);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        $dao = new MySQLDao();
        if ($dao->openConnection() == false)
        {
            $returnValue["status"] = false;
            $returnValue["title"] = "Error";
            $returnValue["message"] = "Connection Could Not Be Established Between Server And Database";
            echo json_encode($returnValue);
        }
        else
        {
            //Decodes data, dont change
            $body = json_decode($param, true);
            $recieved = $body["data"];

            //Gets the result of a query
            //$result = $dao->MySQLDaoMethodName(parameters);

            //Return the result of the query
            //echo json_encode($result);
        }
        $dao->closeConnection();
        return;
    }
?>
```

**Conn.php - this is all the connection info, * out for confidential reasons:***

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    class Conn
    {
        public static $dbhost = "***";
        public static $dbname = "***";
        public static $dbuser = "***";
        public static $dbpass = "***";
    }
?>
```

**MySQLDao.php - this file holds the querys**:

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    //Class for holding queries
    class MySQLDao
    {
        var $dbhost = null;
        var $dbuser = null;
        var $dbpass = null;
        var $mysqli = null;
        var $dbname = null;
        var $result = null;


        //constructor
        function __construct()
        {
            $this->dbhost = Conn::$dbhost;
            $this->dbuser = Conn::$dbuser;
            $this->dbpass = Conn::$dbpass;
            $this->dbname = Conn::$dbname;
        }

        //Attempt a connection to the database
        public function openConnection()
        {   

            //Try and connect to the database
            $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass, $this->dbname);
            //If the connection threw an error, report it
            if (mysqli_connect_errno())
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        //Get method for retrieving the database conection
        public function getConnection()
        {
            return $this->mysqli;
        }

        //Close the connection to the database
        public function closeConnection()
        {
            //If there is a connection to the database then close it
            if ($this->mysqli != null)
                $this->mysqli->close();
        }

        //-----------------------------------QUERY METHODS-------------------------------------

        public function getResults($data)
        {

            $sql = "SELECT room.room_description FROM room WHERE room.room_id = 1";

            $result = $this->mysqli->query($sql);


            //if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
            //  $obj = mysql_fetch_object($result, 'obResults');

            //}

            echo json_encode($result);

            echo($result);

        }

    }
?>
```

Comment: convert `type: "GET",` to `type: "POST",` and check

Comment: Just showing this in the console log: '<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=0)</i>
  <i><font color='#888a85'>empty</font></i>
</pre>'

Comment: If you change that then would also need to check `$_POST` then or `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: The output you are seeing in console is your debug code: `echo var_dump($_GET);` Maybe you need to get rid of those calls and just spit back the valid JSON as it looks like at one point you intended. Test in browser first... when `sitename.com/BaseClass.php?action=getResults` outputs the expected JSON, only then try and get the client side code working.

Comment: I commented out //echo var_dump($_GET);
And put echo json_encode($_GET); but its purely printing out {"action":"getResults"}

Comment: Do you have x-debug? How do you test/debug your API? If you remove / comment out all debugging outputs like `echo json_encode($result);` and `echo($result);` then what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand how to ship data between javscript and php.

1. Your javascript should be posting with $.post() if you want to send an object or array of data.
2. Your php will recieve json from the javascript. You need to use php's json_decode function on it to make it useful to php.
3. If you want the output of your php script to be useful to javascript, you need to encode it with php's json_encode function before returning it to the calling script.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: But I want to send from php to javascript, so I thought I had to post in php so the js could get the data

Comment: Just updated my answer. Please see step 3 for details on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The output is for `echo var_dump($_GET);` I'm sure. I can tell because of the output format is a `var_dump` type. and the success part of your code does not have any output. I mean in this part `else { //Decodes data, dont change ...` the output has been commented out.

I noticed that you are using MySqli but some methods are MySql api like this part of the code

```
//if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
       //  $obj = mysql_fetch_object($result, 'obResults');

//}
```

I assume this code is not complete and in debugging phase as I can see many incomplete methods and function calls.

Also try to use prepared statements with place holders for security.

It is a good practice to use `ob_clean()` before API output as any extra character will destroy the output data and format. However, you will not see errors. There are useful tools for API testing like Browsers Rest Client extensions. The best way for debugging is always debugging tools and frameworks like x-debug.

Do following changes to your code. Hope this helps!

**BaseClass.php:**

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    require("Conn.php");
    require("MySQLDao.php");

    $param=$_REQUEST['action'];

    // echo var_dump($_GET);
    /*
    $handle = fopen("php://input", "rb");
    $param = '';
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $param .= fread($handle, 8192);
    }
    fclose($handle);
    */

    if (empty($param))
    {
        $returnValue["status"] = false;
        $returnValue["title"] = "Error";
        $returnValue["message"] = "No Data Recieved paige" .$param ."...";
        ob_clean();
        echo json_encode($returnValue);
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        $dao = new MySQLDao();
        if ($dao->openConnection() == false)
        {
            $returnValue["status"] = false;
            $returnValue["title"] = "Error";
            $returnValue["message"] = "Connection Could Not Be Established Between Server And Database";

            //Clean up before output
            ob_clean();
            echo json_encode($returnValue);
            exit();
        }
        else
        {
            //Decodes data, dont change
            $body = json_decode($param, true);
            $recieved = $body["data"];

            //Gets the result of a query
            $result = $dao->getResults($recieved);
            //Close connection as fast as possible
            $dao->closeConnection();

            //Return the result of the query
            ob_clean();
            echo json_encode($result);
            exit();
        }
    }
?>
```

**MySQLDao.php**

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    //Class for holding queries
    class MySQLDao
    {
        var $dbhost = null;
        var $dbuser = null;
        var $dbpass = null;
        var $mysqli = null;
        var $dbname = null;
        var $result = null;


        //constructor
        function __construct()
        {
            $this->dbhost = Conn::$dbhost;
            $this->dbuser = Conn::$dbuser;
            $this->dbpass = Conn::$dbpass;
            $this->dbname = Conn::$dbname;
        }

        //Attempt a connection to the database
        public function openConnection()
        {   

            //Try and connect to the database
            $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass, $this->dbname);
            //If the connection threw an error, report it
            if (mysqli_connect_errno())
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        //Get method for retrieving the database conection
        public function getConnection()
        {
            return $this->mysqli;
        }

        //Close the connection to the database
        public function closeConnection()
        {
            //If there is a connection to the database then close it
            if ($this->mysqli != null)
                $this->mysqli->close();
        }

        //-----------------------------------QUERY METHODS-------------------------------------

        public function getResults($data)
        {

            $sql = "SELECT room.room_description FROM room WHERE room.room_id = ?";

            $stsm = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql);
            $stsm->bind_param('i',1);
            $result = $stmt->execute();

            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
              $obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result, 'obResults');
              return $obj;
            }

            return false;
        }

    }
?>
```